# Django ModelForm initial not working for textarea

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django ModelForm, I'm trying to populate it with `initial` values from my views, all fields are populated except for the `textarea` field. I have no idea why. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

views.py

```
name = 'Testing123'
private = True
notes = 'JUST CHECKING'
ctx['header_form'] = NewTemplateForm(initial={'name': name, 'private': private,'notes:': notes})
```

- `private` is a BooleanField, initial works even for that
- `name` is populated
- `notes` is the only field that isn't being populated.

template.html
I'm rendering the form like this:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label>{{form.name.label}}</label>
                {% render_field form.name class="form-control" required="true" %}
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top: 23px">
                <div class="i-checks"><label> {% render_field form.private type="checkbox" %} <i></i> Make this Template Private </label></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="id_notes">{{form.notes.label}}</label>
            {% render_field form.notes class="form-control" %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

forms.py

```
class NewTemplateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SalesTemplate
        fields = {'name', 'notes', 'private'}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewTemplateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['notes'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'md-textarea', 'style': 'height: 75px'})
```

Comment: You should show the form definition. And the template.

Comment: There, edited and added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is a typo in your code and you are passing `'notes:'` as key instead of `'notes'` in this line

```py
ctx['header_form'] = NewTemplateForm(initial={'name': name, 'private': private,
'notes:': notes})  # HERE!
```